# Identifying Patterns by Group in a Data Frame

Tags: r, date, if-statement, dplyr

I currently have a dataset which shows the number of people sick by location per day. For each group (Location) there is an output of 1 (sick) or 0 (not sick) in the 'Sick' column to state whether there is sickness in the area.

**My aim is to create a new column that identifies periods of long term sickness and labels any row that contributes to this.**

The following data frame shows the sample data:

```
Current <- structure(list(Location = c("Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", 
"Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", 
"Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid"), Date = structure(c(16122, 
16123, 16124, 16125, 16126, 16127, 16128, 16129, 16130, 16131, 
16132, 16133, 16134, 16135, 16136), class = "Date"), Sick = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), .Names = c("Location", 
"Date", "Sick"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The rule I would like to apply to the new column is the following:

*# If in any 6 day period there are 4 days of sickness, all days with a sickness recorded should have “Long Term” entered in the new computed variable ('Type'). If this condition is not met then “Short Term” should be entered in the new computed variable which is called 'Type'.

For this to work I need it perform the calculation by group. Location is the group in this analysis so I aim to be able to class days based on location. I have not been able to work this out.

The desired output would look like this:

```
Desired <- structure(list(Location = c("Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", 
    "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", 
    "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Madrid"), Date = structure(c(16122, 
    16123, 16124, 16125, 16126, 16127, 16128, 16129, 16130, 16131, 
    16132, 16133, 16134, 16135, 16136), class = "Date"), Sick = c(1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), Type = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "Long Term", "Long Term", "Long Term", "Long Term", NA, 
    "Long Term", "Long Term", "Long Term", "Long Term", NA)), .Names = c("Location", 
    "Date", "Sick", "Type"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any help on this is much appreciated and also on any feedback regarding the question style and layout is helpful.

Currently, I have the problem of only the Window term that meets the ifelse criteria being labelled 'Long Term'. What I need is for all observations that form the window testing and have sickness as 1 to be labelled 'Long Term':

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to follow @Noobie's suggestions to find the start of the "Long Term" periods, then extend the entries from there. Here, I am using `rollsum` from `zoo` instead, just because that is what I am familiar with working with. Importantly, this assumes that there is an entry for every day (if not, consider using `complete` with `full_seq` from `tidyr`) and that they are in order (if not, use `arrange`).

First, find spots that start long term periods:

```
temp <-
  Current %>%
  mutate(rollCount = zoo::rollsum(Sick, 6
                                  , fill = NA
                                  , align = "left")
         , startLong = rollCount >= 4)
```

Then, add 5 days to each of those starting points (using `unique` to avoid re-setting multiple times):

```
toFill <-
  sapply(which(temp$startLong), function(x){
    x + (0:5)
  }) %>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  unique()
```

Then, add a column for the `Type`, and set it to `Long Term` just for those that we pulled in `toFill`:

```
temp$Type <- NA    
temp$Type[toFill] <- "Long Term"
```

Returns:

```
   Location       Date  Sick rollCount startLong      Type
      <chr>     <date> <dbl>     <dbl>     <lgl>     <chr>
1    Madrid 2014-02-21     1         3     FALSE      <NA>
2    Madrid 2014-02-22     1         3     FALSE      <NA>
3    Madrid 2014-02-23     0         3     FALSE      <NA>
4    Madrid 2014-02-24     0         4      TRUE Long Term
5    Madrid 2014-02-25     0         4      TRUE Long Term
6    Madrid 2014-02-26     1         5      TRUE Long Term
7    Madrid 2014-02-27     1         5      TRUE Long Term
8    Madrid 2014-02-28     1         5      TRUE Long Term
9    Madrid 2014-03-01     1         5      TRUE Long Term
10   Madrid 2014-03-02     0         4      TRUE Long Term
11   Madrid 2014-03-03     1        NA        NA Long Term
12   Madrid 2014-03-04     1        NA        NA Long Term
13   Madrid 2014-03-05     1        NA        NA Long Term
14   Madrid 2014-03-06     1        NA        NA Long Term
15   Madrid 2014-03-07     0        NA        NA Long Term
```

If you want to use this for multiple different locations, it is probably best to wrap it in a function, then use `group_by` and `mutate` to add the column.

```
myFunction <- function(x){
  temp <-
    data.frame(Sick = x) %>%
    mutate(rollCount = zoo::rollsum(Sick, 6
                                    , fill = NA
                                    , align = "left")
           , startLong = rollCount >= 4)

  toFill <-
    sapply(which(temp$startLong), function(x){
      x + (0:5)
    }) %>%
    as.numeric() %>%
    unique()

  temp$Type <- NA

  temp$Type[toFill] <- "Long Term"

  return(temp$Type)
}
```

Then, apply it to the data. Note that after applying the function, I am using `ifelse` to set the value of `Type` to "Short Term" if there is sickness and an empty string ("") if there is not.

```
Current %>%
  group_by(Location) %>%
  mutate(Type = myFunction(Sick)
         , Type = ifelse(Sick == 1
                         , ifelse(!is.na(Type)
                                  , Type, "Short Term")
                         , ""))
```

Returns:

```
   Location       Date  Sick       Type
      <chr>     <date> <dbl>      <chr>
1    Madrid 2014-02-21     1 Short Term
2    Madrid 2014-02-22     1 Short Term
3    Madrid 2014-02-23     0           
4    Madrid 2014-02-24     0  Long Term
5    Madrid 2014-02-25     0  Long Term
6    Madrid 2014-02-26     1  Long Term
7    Madrid 2014-02-27     1  Long Term
8    Madrid 2014-02-28     1  Long Term
9    Madrid 2014-03-01     1  Long Term
10   Madrid 2014-03-02     0  
11   Madrid 2014-03-03     1  Long Term
12   Madrid 2014-03-04     1  Long Term
13   Madrid 2014-03-05     1  Long Term
14   Madrid 2014-03-06     1  Long Term
15   Madrid 2014-03-07     0
```

and should respect the different locations (again, assumes all dates are entered and rows are sorted by date).

Comment: Hi @Mark Peterson, Thanks for this response. That looks to be good although is it possible to just have the Type label on observations where 'Sick' = 1?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "just have" the label. So in the edit, I set it to empty ("") when there is not sickness and to "Short Term" when there is sickness. You could put this in the function instead, but it seemed reasonable enough to pull out here.

Comment: For example row 10 on your 'Returns' table has 'Long Term' in the Type variable despite there being no sickness on that day. What would need to be adjusted to only have labels for 'Type' when 'Sick' =1?

Comment: By the way I get the error: Error: k <= n is not TRUE. Have you seen this before? On the larger dataset I am working with it comes up after the rollsum function.

Comment: I see now what you meant, and have edited again (needed to change the `ifelse` a bit). My guess is that you have a Location with 6 or fewer dates entered (the size of the window is called `k`, so this suggests you have fewer points than the width of the window)

Comment: Thanks, it is all working now. I switched back to the roll_sum and it fixed the NA problem. Great all good now. Thanks for your help with this, very impressive!

Answer (score 0):

solution:

use rolling sums in Pandas

```
df['flag'] = df.sickness.rolling(window = 6).sum()
df['long_term'] = (df['flag'] > 4)
```

or in R

```
library(RcppRoll)
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, flag = RcppRoll::roll_sum(x = sickness, 2),
       long_term = if_else(flag > 4, 'Bim!', 'Boom!'))
```

Comment: Wrong tag. You're offering a pandas solution.

Comment: haha indeed! anyways, the idea stays the same. OP should use rolling sums here.

Comment: Maybe you should change your answer then.

Comment: Hi, that solution works other than it only labels a day where the long_term condition is met. I was hoping for all sickness obersvations in that window to take the label of "long term if the if statement was true. Thank you

Comment: @Noobie any idea how to label based on that criteria? Thanks